# Does Saxon XSLT processor optimize for setting a tunnel parameter to its current value?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I'm curious if Saxon XSLT parser will optimize tunnel parameter passing - if the same value is used, is it recreated?  Or, does it use the current copy?

I'm not sure it is necessary to provide an example, but I've tried to illustrate my particular use case below.

Example input xml:

```
<formDefinition sysid="1">
    <subform sysid="2">
        <subform layoutGrid="8" sysid="3">
            <field weight="2" sysid="4">
                <bind match="none" />
                <type><date /></type>
            </field>
        </subform>
    </subform>
</formDefinition>
```

To provide some context - the subform element is similar to an HTML DIV element, and the field element is similar to an HTML INPUT element.  The layoutGrid attribute can be set or overriden by subforms, and used by descendants such as fields.

My actual stylesheet and 'formDefinition' are much larger, using many tunnel parameters with many interrelated settings that are difficult to partition, so it is hard to avoid resetting the parameters to their existing values.

I've tried below to give a general flow to illustrate how I am setting only one of the tunnel parameters.

Example stylesheet -

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[@sysid]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="render" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/formDefinition" mode="render">
    <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:next-match />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="subform" mode="render">
    <xsl:param name="pLayoutGrid" as="xs:decimal" tunnel="yes" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="effLayoutGrid" select="$pLayoutGrid" />
        <xsl:next-match />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="field" mode="render">
   <xsl:param name="pLayoutGrid" as="xs:decimal" tunnel="yes" />
     <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="effLayoutGrid" select="$pLayoutGrid" />
        <xsl:next-match />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="render">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(@sysid)]" />
    <xsl:call-template name="step" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="step">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[@sysid]">
        <xsl:with-param name="pLayoutGrid" as="xs:decimal" tunnel="yes">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="layoutGrid" />
        </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/formDefinition" mode="layoutGrid">
    <xsl:sequence select="xs:decimal(12)" />  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="subform" mode="layoutGrid">
    <xsl:param name="pLayoutGrid" as="xs:decimal" tunnel="yes" />
    <!-- potentially resetting the same value here -->
    <xsl:sequence select="(@layoutGrid, $pLayoutGrid)[1]" />  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="field" mode="layoutGrid">
    <xsl:param name="pLayoutGrid" as="xs:decimal" tunnel="yes" />
    <!-- setting value to current value -->
    <xsl:sequence select="$pLayoutGrid" />  
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<formDefinition>
    <subform effLayoutGrid="12">
        <subform effLayoutGrid="12">
            <field effLayoutGrid="8">
                <bind match="none" />
                <type>
                    <date />
                </type>
            </field>
        </subform>
    </subform>
</formDefinition>
```

My question, in context of the example - does resetting the pLayoutGrid tunnel parameter actually create a new 'object', or does it reuse the current one, when the value is set back to its current value?

In my full code, I also have tunnel parameters that are xml elements / trees.  I mention this as I wonder if there is a difference between 'basic' types and xml elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Saxon calls a template it first creates a new XPathContext object; this corresponds to the "dynamic context" defined in the XPath and XSLT specs (except for the parts that don't vary within an execution scope, like current date/time). The new XPathContext object copies some aspects of the caller's context and reinitializes other parts (like the local variables).

The XPathContext object holds a field called tunnelParams whose value is a ParameterSet; this is a set of name/value pairs rather like a HashMap. When a template is called a new ParameterSet object is created containing the union of the entries in the ParameterSet passed by the caller and the new tunnel parameters declared by the callee. The entries in the ParameterSet are copied, but of course the values themselves don't need to be copied because all XDM values are immutable.

Having said that, I'm having a bit of trouble understanding exactly what your question means. If you "reset" a tunnel parameter to an existing value (say, a value in a global variable) then the ParameterSet is just going to contain a reference to that value. If you set it using some computation, like

```
<xsl:with-param name="tun-par" select="23 to 50"/>
```

then it's not going to recognize that the new value is the same as some previous value.

Comment: Thank you Dr. Kay.  Based on your explanation, I anticipate the cost of redeclaring the tunnel parameter in my code should be low.

Comment: Please measure it and share the results.